# Telerik MVC - errors with manually registered JavaScript files

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, telerik, datepicker, partial-views

I want to use Telerik DatePickers and IntegerTextBoxes on my Partial View loaded via jQuery. Following the [troubleshooting guide](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-troubleshooting.html), I have manually added the requisite JavaScript files to the ScriptRegistrar thusly:

**Site.Master**

```
    .
    .
    .    
    <%= Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group => group.Compress(true).Combined(true)
         .Add("telerik.calendar.js")
         .Add("telerik.datepicker.js")
         .Add("telerik.textbox.js"))
     %>
</body>
</html>
```

But, when the relevant page loads, Chrome is giving me the following errors:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'calendar' of undefined
>   aspnet-scripts.telerikstatic.com/mvcz/2010.3.1027/telerik.calendar.min.js
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'datetime' of undefined
>   aspnet-scripts.telerikstatic.com/mvcz/2010.3.1027/telerik.datepicker.min.js
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'textbox' of undefined
>   aspnet-scripts.telerikstatic.com/mvcz/2010.3.1027/telerik.textbox.min.js
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an
>   Object> has no method 'tTextBox'
>   localhost:51280/SystemChange/SystemChangeMain
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an
>   Object> has no method 'tTextBox'
>   localhost:51280/SystemChange/SystemChangeMainst

---

I have also tried adding the 'add script' code in the partial view. No change.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main file "telerik.common.js" does not seem to have been loaded. It is required by all components and should be included first. Check the [Required JavaScript files help topic](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-required-javascript-files.html) for additional info.

Comment: Thanks! telerik.common.min.js WAS showing up as loaded in Chrome, which is why I didn't think to add it to the manual list. But, when I added it manually, at your suggestion, every works great.